# $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ is integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

I'm was browsing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96400/mathbbqx-y-langle-x2y2-1-rangle-is-an-integral-domain?rq=1), where it is proven the quotient field of $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ is isomorphic to the rational function field $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ under the isomorphism
$$
(x,y) \mapsto \left( \frac{2t}{t^2+1}, \frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1} \right).
$$
How can this isomorphism be used to show $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ is normal in its quotient field?

> I identified $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ with $\mathbb{Q}\left[\frac{2t}{t^2+1}, \frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1} \right]$, and was trying to show this is integrally closed in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$.

If $f/g\in\mathbb{Q}(t)$, with $f,g$ coprime, is integral over $\mathbb{Q}[2t/(t^2+1),(t^2-1)/(t^2+1)]$, then 
$$
(f/g)^n+h_{n-1}(f/g)^{n-1}+\cdots+h_1(f/g)+h_0=0,\qquad h_i\in \mathbb{Q}[2t/(t^2+1),(t^2-1)/(t^2+1)].
$$
Multiplying through by $g^n$, I found the relation
$$
f^n=g(-h_{n-1}f^{n-1}-\cdots-h_0g^{n-1})
$$
so any prime dividing $g$ divides $f$, so $g$ is constant, and in fact $f/g\in\mathbb{Q}[t]$. I was hoping to see that is is in fact in $\mathbb{Q}[2t/(t^2+1),(t^2-1)/(t^2+1)]$, but I think I've made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Let's prove that $R=\mathbb{Q}\left[\frac{2t}{t^2+1},\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}\right]$ is integrally closed.

We have $\mathbb{Q}\left[\frac{2t}{t^2+1},\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}\right]=\mathbb{Q}\left[\frac{1}{t^2+1},\frac{t}{t^2+1}\right]$. It's obvious that $\mathbb Q(t)$ is its field of fractions.  Let $f(t)/g(t)\in\mathbb Q(t)$ integral over $R$ with $\gcd(f(t),g(t))=1$. For any element $h\in R$ there is $r\in\mathbb N$ such that  $(t^2+1)^rh\in\mathbb Q[t]$. Consider an integral dependence relation $$(f/g)^n+h_{n-1}(f/g)^{n-1}+\cdots+h_1(f/g)+h_0=0$$ with $h_i\in R$ and multiply this by $(t^2+1)^{nr}$ with $r$ large enough in order to get an integral dependence relation for $(t^2+1)^rf(t)/g(t)$ over $\mathbb Q[t]$. Since $\mathbb Q[t]$ is integrally closed we get $(t^2+1)^rf(t)/g(t)\in\mathbb Q[t]$, and therefore $g(t)\mid(t^2+1)^r$. Since $t^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ we have $g(t)=(t^2+1)^s$. Now it's clear that $f(t)/g(t)\in R$.

Comment: It might be a silly question. But how do you see that $\frac{1}{t^2+1} \in \mathbb{Q}[\frac{2t}{t^2+1},\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}]?$

Comment: @Youngsu: $\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1} = 1 - 2\left(\frac{1}{t^2+1}\right)$

Answer (score -2):

Due to both denominator's being the same that ring  is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbf{Q}[2t, t^2-1]$. That is, the subring of $\mathbf{Q}[t]$ generated by $2t$ and $t^2-1$. But in the presence of $2t$ we do not need $t^2-1$. So this subring can be  generated by just $2t$. So this is isomorphic to the PID $\mathbf{Q}[2t]$, hence normal.

Comment: $\mathbb Q[2t]=\mathbb Q[t]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[2t/(t^2+1),(t^2-1)/(t^2+1)]$ can't be isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[t]$ since it's not a UFD.